# How to create anchor tag link that works only on right click

Tags: javascript, reactjs, href

I have a requirement like I need to use right click for open anchor link on new tab also normal click should not work there.

The below code works good. but, if I click the link after "right click -> open new tab" action the "#" symbol added in URL like "https://example.com/currentPage#"

```
     <a href={void(0)}   onContextMenu={(e)=>{
                      const {currentTarget } = e;
                      (currentTarget as HTMLAnchorElement).href = "/target-link"
                      setTimeout(()=>{(currentTarget as HTMLAnchorElement).href = "#"}, 100)
                      return false;
      }}>
          click here
     </a>
```

so I need something like..

```
(currentTarget as HTMLAnchorElement).href = {void(0)}
```

Comment: Hmm, what about using a label styled like a hyperlink? Then you do not have to bother with updating the href or any other link-specific things. You just open/close the relevant pages with JS.

Comment: Thanks @shilly, but I need default browser right click popup which includes "open in new tab" option.. also it need to open the link that specified by code if I click "open new window" option. If I use lable for that it doesn't open the popup with  "open new window" option on right click

Answer (score 1):

You can add `href` as an empty string and add an `onClick` listener to prevent the default behavior. Like this:

```js
<a href="" onClick={e => {
  e.preventDefault()}}
  // Some other logic
>
This is link
</a>
```